# How to flicker multiple sets of text one after another

Tags: html, css

I am mimicking the Windows 10 start up screen. For those of you familiar with the startup, I have the color transitions complete and one set of flickering text ("Hello!"). But I have no idea how to add new sets of text that will flicker following the ("Hello!") Text.
I've tried to research this but have had no success

The final question is how to flicker multiple sets of text one after another

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: linear-gradient(124deg, #0095f0, #e81d1d, #0095f0, #0095f0, #1de840, #ff0000, #f0f0f0, #dd00f3, #009900);
  background-size: 1800% 1800%;
  -webkit-animation: rainbow 18s ease infinite;
  -z-animation: rainbow 25s ease infinite;
  -o-animation: rainbow 25s ease infinite;
  animation: rainbow 25s ease infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rainbow {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 82%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 19%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 82%
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes rainbow {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 82%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 19%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 82%
  }
}

@-o-keyframes rainbow {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 82%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 19%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 82%
  }
}

@keyframes rainbow {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 82%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 19%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 82%
  }
}

#Message {
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-top: 250px;
}

@keyframes flickerAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes flickerAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes flickerAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes flickerAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.animate-flicker {
  -webkit-animation: flickerAnimation 10s infinite;
  -moz-animation: flickerAnimation 10s infinite;
  -o-animation: flickerAnimation 10s infinite;
  animation: flickerAnimation 10s infinite;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-top: 250px;
}

#greet {
  font-family: roboto;
  font-weight: 150;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="animate-flicker" align="center">
    <p id="greet">Hello!</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't really understand your problem.. You want to add some other text that will do the same effect as hello but later ? IF so, you could add that text in the html and give it an animation-delay to start it's effect after hello

Answer (score 1):

I have translated your question in following requirements:

1. Show several words consecutively at the same spot.
2. Apply an animation on each word.

My animation displays an element 10 times for a short period of time and hides it again. `animation-delay` ensures that the animation on the second word starts after the first animation has finished and the animation on the third word starts after the second animation has finished.

To center words I positioned them absolute. This was necessary because I could not integrate `display: inline;` or `display: none;` in the keyframe animation (property display is not animatable).

```css
span {
  animation-name: flickerAnimation;
  animation-duration: 0.1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 10;   
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
span:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
span:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

@keyframes flickerAnimation {
  0% {opacity: 1;}
  80% {opacity: 1;}
  81% {opacity: 0;}
  100% {opacity: 0;}
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <span>First</span>
    <span>Second</span>
    <span>Third</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this and adjusted the delay times , however now the texts overlap each other 

Is it possible to disable a set of text once it's appeared?

Comment: `animation-duration: 0.1s;`, `animation-iteration-count: 10;`, `animation-delay: 1s;` and `animation-delay: 2s;` relate to each other. 

Duration multiplicated with iteration-count results in the total amount used for a complete animation (0.1s x 10 = 1s). Hence the delay is 1 and 2 seconds. If you have 30 iteration the delay for the second animation would be 3s and for the third animation 6s.